# How to enable UDST in java?

Tags: java, ebpf, dtrace

I have created a new GCP instance and used defaulted Debian system.
Then, I use `apt` to install the `default-java` package, but they're no USDT in `libjvm.so`. I don't know why?

information:

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux bpf-test1 4.19.0-18-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.208-1 (2021-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ whereis java
java: /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.13" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1deb10u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.13+8-post-Debian-1deb10u1, mixed mode, sharing)

$ readelf -n $JAVA_HOME/lib/server/libjvm.so
Displaying notes found in: .note.gnu.build-id
  Owner                 Data size   Description
  GNU                  0x00000014   NT_GNU_BUILD_ID (unique build ID bitstring)
    Build ID: 5a4af8c3edd4e64e7fd351d2e18dce9947db4d22

$ ps -ef|grep java
xxx   23001 22956  1 13:08 pts/0    00:00:30 java -jar xxx.jar
xxx   23157 23042  0 13:44 pts/1    00:00:00 grep java

$ sudo javathreads-bpfcc  23001
Error attaching USDT probes: the specified pid might not contain the
given language's runtime, or the runtime was not built with the required
USDT probes. Look for a configure flag similar to --with-dtrace or
--enable-dtrace. To check which probes are present in the process, use the
tplist tool.

$ cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep BPF
CONFIG_CGROUP_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF=y
CONFIG_BPF_SYSCALL=y
# CONFIG_BPF_JIT_ALWAYS_ON is not set
CONFIG_IPV6_SEG6_BPF=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_BPF=m
# CONFIG_BPFILTER is not set
CONFIG_NET_CLS_BPF=m
CONFIG_NET_ACT_BPF=m
CONFIG_BPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_STREAM_PARSER=y
CONFIG_LWTUNNEL_BPF=y
CONFIG_HAVE_EBPF_JIT=y
CONFIG_BPF_EVENTS=y
# CONFIG_BPF_KPROBE_OVERRIDE is not set
# CONFIG_TEST_BPF is not set

$ cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep TRACEPOINT
CONFIG_TRACEPOINTS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_SYSCALL_TRACEPOINTS=y
# CONFIG_TRACEPOINT_BENCHMARK is not set
```

Comment: The images on GCP might very well have kernels built with some features disabled to save on space, boot time or to minimize attack surface. Can you add the output of `cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep BPF` and `cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep TRACEPOINT` to your question?

Comment: Been added, please take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Kernel has nothing to do USDT probes, since these have to be in the `libjvm.so`. Unfortunately you didn't specify your debian version, and as far as I know there is no [default-java](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye&searchon=names&keywords=default-java) package in the debian (although there is `default-[jdk|jre] package`). From your java version I could guess that you using [this package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/default-jdk). Anyway, in order to have `USDT` probes openjdk has to be complied with `--enable-dtrace` flag, which isn't used in that package. When `openjdk` is compiled with this flag you'll have this:

```
readelf -n /path/to/openjdk/lib/server/libjvm.so

  stapsdt              0x0000002f       NT_STAPSDT (SystemTap probe descriptors)
    Provider: hotspot
    Name: thread__yield
    Location: 0x000000000098745b, Base: 0x000000000107e7f4, Semaphore: 0x0000000000000000
    Arguments: 
  stapsdt              0x0000003d       NT_STAPSDT (SystemTap probe descriptors)
    Provider: hotspot
    Name: thread__sleep__begin
    Location: 0x000000000098ff64, Base: 0x000000000107e7f4, Semaphore: 0x0000000000000000
    Arguments: -8@%r12
  stapsdt              0x00000039       NT_STAPSDT (SystemTap probe descriptors)
    Provider: hotspot
    Name: thread__sleep__end
    Location: 0x000000000098ffa3, Base: 0x000000000107e7f4, Semaphore: 0x0000000000000000
    Arguments: -4@$0
  stapsdt              0x00000039       NT_STAPSDT (SystemTap probe descriptors)
    Provider: hotspot
    Name: thread__sleep__end
    Location: 0x0000000000990100, Base: 0x000000000107e7f4, Semaphore: 0x0000000000000000
    Arguments: -4@$1
```

So your options is either, build openjdk yourself and ensure to use `--enable-dtrace` flag (this would require [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) as dependency) or use package that has been provided by someone else. As for prebuild package, I can recommend [this](https://adoptium.net/index.html?variant=openjdk11&jvmVariant=hotspot) prebuild package. Unfortunately, there is no `*.deb` package there (there is only `.tar.gz`), but I know for sure that it has been built with `--enable-dtrace`. I'm recommending this because I know that certain distros using these packages (for example [Gentoo](https://github.com/gentoo/gentoo/blob/master/dev-java/openjdk-bin/openjdk-bin-11.0.14_p9-r1.ebuild#L9)).